# Which operator to chain Observables conditionally?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'd like to load some data, which is **paginated**, from a REST API, into my Angular app. Typically, the API is sending me data following this structure :

```
{
    "next": null,
    "results": [
        {"id": 7, "name": "Alicia"},
        {"id": 8, "name": "Ted"},
        {"id": 9, "name": "Marshall"}
    ]
}
```

Where `next` is the url to `GET/` the next data page request. Obviously, I don't know in advance the number of page I need to iterate to fully load the data.

I wrote the following **working code** in order fully get the data ([Working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/goAqC0zjYCtx1H2LkBFP?p=preview)) :

```
public loadPeople( next?:string ): void {
    if(!next) next = 'api/1.json';

    this.http.get(next)
        .pipe(
          map( (response: Response) => response.json())
        )
        .subscribe( (data: any) => {
          this._people = this._people.concat(data.results);
          this._peopleSubject.next(this._people);
          if(data.next) this.loadPeople(data.next);
        })
}
```

However, I do lack of experience with Rx.JS and I'm pretty sure there's a better, cleaner way to do it, by chaining `Observables` using an operator, but I can't put my hand on it.

Any idea of an operator I could use ? Thanks !

Comment: The best way to do such things is to use ngrx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `concatMap` and `concat` operators:

```
public loadPage( next:string ): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get(next)
        .pipe(
          map( (response: Response) => response.json() )
          concatMap((data: any) => {
            if (data.next) {
              return Observable.of(data.results).concat(this.loadPage(data.next));
            }
            return Observable.of(data.results);
          })
        );
}

public loadPeople( next?:string ): void {
    if(!next) next = 'api/1.json';

    this.loadPage(next)
        .subscribe( (people: string[]) => {
            this._people = this._people.concat(people);
            this._peopleSubject.next(this._people);
        })
}
```

You will need the following imports:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'
import { concat, concatMap,  map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Comment: Ended up doing nearly the same thing. Thanks ! ;)

Comment: Is there a way to skip to the next concatMap (or whatever operator)? for example if a certain condition is true return a http call else move on to the next operator - thanks

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but it's similar as the `if (data.next)` inside concatMap lambda: it's the condition for continuing or ending the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Map and Subscribe** or **MergeMap** for the same .
Map and subscribe would be used as

```
this.http.get('/api/people/1')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(character => {
    this.http.get(character.homeworld).subscribe(homeworld => {
      character.homeworld = homeworld;
      this.loadedCharacter = character;
    });
  });
```

}

But this way we can note two things

- First we are starting to see this nested pyramid structure in nesting
  our Observables which isnt very readable.
- second our two requests were sequential

So we can use mergemap to map/iterate over the Observable values like

```
this.homeworld = this.http.get('/api/people/1')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .mergeMap(character => this.http.get(character.homeworld))
```

}

Thanks to ** Cory Rylan** who has explained this beautifully [enter link description here](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs)

Comment: how does it solve this question its just chaning observables

Comment: matter of adding a single if condition in the code. Question was about using observable effectively ..Atleast thats what i understood !

Comment: Not sure how I can concatenate the data from all three API calls though, using mergeMap though. I thought of using forkJoin() but I don't want to wait for the data to load entirely to start displaying it. Do you have an idea of how I could do that ? Thanks for your help !

Comment: see https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html for merging related things.Also Rxjs documentation should help you better with your query.Also if the order of emission is important you might have to consider using concatMap .You can find the examples for that as wel in the link provided

Comment: glad to help :)